# Webkit based browsers on Mac refuse to load certain websites or resources, other browsers work fine from the same machine

Tags: google-chrome, safari, webkit

OK, this one has really been puzzling me.

Certain websites (such as instapaper.com ) or certain resources (such as the CSS and images for icanhazcheezeburger.com sites) refuse to load at all in Safari or Chrome on any of my Mac machines. Rebooting the machine doesn't fix it.

If I use another browser, such as Firefox or a browser on my iPhone or in my Windows virtual machine, the pages load just fine.

When the whole page errors out, Safari displays an error:

```
"WebKit encountered an internal error" WebKitErrorDomain:300
```

This is all from within my home network. Any ideas what could possibly be causing such bizarre behavior?